# mac keyboard function keys mapping

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I lost my configuration or never had it.
I need to send shift+F1 and ctrl+F1, shift+F2 and ctrl+F2 and so on to the terminal since I'm connecting to a linux machine via ssh.
well, my current config is missing these string mappings as you can see in the image.
do you know what are the string mappings for those key combinations ?
thanks.[image: key mappings]

UPDATE:
in some stackexchange i found this command:

```
$>for x in {1..12}; do echo -n "F$x "; tput kf$x | cat -A; echo; done
```

can you help me to print the strings for shift + f1 ?

Answer (score 0):

First: From this page http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html, you will understand that shift-F1 maps to F11, shift-F2 maps to F12 and so on.(Search the page 'a summary of the keyboard mapping' without ', you will see the list).

Second: From this page http://aperiodic.net/phil/archives/Geekery/term-function-keys.html, you will know F1 or F11 or F20 maps to what string(at the bottom).

More to say:
If you want to send Shift-F1 to a program through Terminal, these will happen:

1. You hit Shift-F1, the Terminal will translate the Shift-F1 to a string sequence
2. The string sequence will be sent to the program

For example, you send a Shift-F1 to emacs through the Terminal,the Terminal translate it into string sequence and send the string sequence to emacs, emacs will recognise it as a key strokes then do something.

I'm not quite familiar about this, so this answer may be not right.